# Scene screen is stuck

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and I'm trying to make my own game (or at least learn to). I have a problem in the scene screen.

The scene screen is stuck on this mode and I don't know how to bring it back to the original camera view(hope you guys understand what I'm meaning), Tried to search how to do it but couldn't specified what I want, please help.

[image: screenshot of unity]

Comment: Can you give me more information? Do you want to set UI on your camera view?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean with `stuck on this mode`

Answer (score 1):

The `Canvas` when in `Overlay` mode turns out to be a giant object compared with normal scale.

You are just too far from your objects, to return to normal you can navigate manually right clicking `Scene` window and moving with `WASD` and `QE`.

Another workaround is that you use the FIND shortcut like following:

1. Click the object you want to find on `Hierarchy` window
2. Move your cursor to `Scene` window without clicking
3. Press `F` on your keyboard

If perforned correctly the `Scene` camera will find that object and you will be right back to where you were.